# Css3 animations with same durations end at different times when triggered by the same event

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I am attempting to create a menu that appears to slide in from the left using a transform on the menu itself and a width change on the menu button. Both animations are triggered through javascript when the button is pressed.

If the durations are set to the same number the button moves ahead of the menu with both ending at different times. If the durations are tweaked so they end at the same time they take turns overtaking each other even though both are using a linear timing-function.

This seems completely illogical, how can the identical durations and timings be displayed at different speeds and lengths?

I cloned the code on my site regarding this issue and it can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/3g83t54t/, for quciker reference here are the keyframes and animation rules I have asigned.

```
a#menu.closed:hover{
    -webkit-animation:button_fade .1s ease-in forwards;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 7px 0 4px;
    width: 50px;
}
    a#menu.closed:hover div.blurb{
    -webkit-animation:button_blurb_fade .1s ease-in forwards;
    }
    a#menu.open{
    -webkit-animation:button_stretch 1s linear forwards;
    padding: 0 4px;
        width: 100%;
    }
div#sl_nav{
    -webkit-animation:menu_slide_in 1s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes button_blurb_fade{
    to{
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes button_fade{
    to{
        background: #fff;
        border-right: 1px solid #000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes menu_slide_in {
    from{-webkit-transform:translateX(-326px);}
    to{-webkit-transform:translateX(0);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes button_stretch {
    from{width: 50px;}
    to{max-width: 377px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this style:

```
@-webkit-keyframes button_stretch {
    from{width: 50px;}
    to{max-width: 377px;}
}
```

To:

```
@-webkit-keyframes button_stretch {
    from{width: 50px;}
    to{width: 377px;}
}
```

<strike>I'd like to tell you why, but I don't really know. ;)</strike> I *think* `max-width` causes the button to respond more to the other elements which are also resizing, which is why it is lagging. By specifying `width`, you just force it to be that size, no concessions.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vd8pf09w/)

Comment: Thanks so much, this was driving me insane.